# java generics covariance

Tags: java, generics, alias, covariance

I am having trouble understanding the following article:
[http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20161204181636/https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp07018/index.html)

Under,

> Generics are not covariant

the author states,

> Because ln is a List, adding a
> Float to it seems perfectly legal. But
> if ln were aliased with li, then it
> would break the type-safety promise
> implicit in the definition of li --
> that it is a list of integers, which
> is why generic types cannot be
> covariant.

I can't understand the part where it says
"if ln were aliased with li". What does the author means by alias?(reference?). The code snippet above the quoted line seems to illustrate WHAT is illegal in java and not WHY. It would be very helpful to me if somebody could explain with an example.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: IIRC, generic types are not covariant because they could not change how arrays were implemented/used in previous versions of Java (backward compatibility), does it ring a bell to someone?

Comment: @Skeptic, Arrays are an example of what a covariant generics implementation might look like - it would throw runtime exceptions. Java can't do that because the generics are erased at runtime, so it can only control it via limiting covariance.

Comment: @Yishai, that problem with arrays was discussed by Steele in a presentation named "Growing a Language" which I can't seem to find right now.

Comment: That IBM link appears to be dead, but there's a copy at the Wayback Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20121104021805/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html

Comment: @Skeptic the written version of the Steele presentation did not mention the array problem. However, it is quite a good read. It is at http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs655/readings/steele.pdf or via the Wayback machine, http://web.archive.org/web/20131117030438/http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs655/readings/steele.pdf

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> ln = li; // illegal
ln.add(new Float(3.1415));
```

In Java, Integer inherits from Number`(java.lang.Number)`, so intuitively, anything that is an Integer`(java.lang.Integer)` is also a number, but what that article points out is that with generics it does not work that way, because considering that example, you could end up putting a float (which is a Number) into a `List<Integer>`, which is illegal because a float is not an integer.

**Conclusion:** Generics are not covariant.

**Note:** I recommend you read *Effective Java (2nd Edition) Chapter 5: Generics.*

Comment: Thanks. 8) I thought the explanation had nothing to do with the code snippet. Silly me.

Comment: +1 for the reco to read Effective Java.  I've been writing code for many years, and picked up EJ a month ago and immediately learned 5 or 6 hugely important strategies.

Comment: This article is also immensely helpful: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html

Comment: A bit off topic but C# does allow collections to have a type of covariance in a safe manner. checkout http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/collection-covariance-with-c-40.html

Comment: So, if I had a method returning type `List<Number>` I could in principle safely return a `List<Integer>` because the integer list would stop being referenced afterwards? (Not saying java supports this without warnings)

Answer (score 11):

If you could do something like this:

```
List<Float> foo;
List<Object> bar;

foo = new ArrayList<Float>();
bar = foo;

foo.add(1.0f);
bar.add("Hello");
```

things would go VERY wrong.  In this example bar is an alias for foo, and if you could do it you would lose the type safety that are the main reason that generics exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wasn't sure about the alias part. This confirms my assumption was right.

Comment: Ah! So now "Hello" is not only in `bar` (which would probably be fine), but also in `foo`. Finally it makes sense :) I guess then I could declare a list casting method, which would have to copy the list, hm.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class vechicle {
void drive(){
}
}
class car extends vechicle{
        //Covariance
    vechicle getObject(){
        return new car();
    }
        //contravariance
    car getmyObject(){
        return (car) new vechicle(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException will raise at `return (car) new vechicle();`