# Why is List<String> not a subtype of List<Object>?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java generics covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance)

I am trying to make sense of the fact that  `List<String>` is **not** a subtype of `List<Object>`.

In effective Java, Josh Bloch notes that although it may seem counter-intuitive,it does make sense. The reason he stated is that you can put any Object in `List<Object>`, but can only put String in `List<String>`. I am not sure how this justifies why the String list is not a subtype of Object list.

Maybe I am confused by the term `subtype`. What I think it means is that when S is a subtype of T, an instance of S is an instance of T. Therefore, for `List<String>` to be a subtype of `List<Object>`, Object has to be a super class of String, which it technically is. Any idea where my reasoning went wrong?

Comment: I am not sure it is a duplicate. Do you have a link?

Comment: please post example code.  do you means something like: `List<Object> list = new LinkedList<String>()`?

Comment: I am not coding. I was reading the book, and I found that statement and it confused me.

Comment: @why-el: There's no example in the book to illustrate the point? That seems...odd.

Comment: I don't understand the "too localized" close-vote at all. How is it too localized? If it's not a duplicate, it's a good question.

Comment: I think this is pretty much the same (has the same answer as the currently only answer here): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it might be. Anyhow, I am not reading the book sequentially, so maybe he went a little bit further on that point somewhere else.

Comment: @alpian Yep, I think thats more or less the same. And a good answer too. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

```
List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Object> o = s;
o.add(new Object());
String first = s.get(0);  // boom
```

Comment: +1 for the comment. Lol!

Comment: I don't know why that's so damned funny, but it is!

Comment: Liskov substitution principle: if `A` is a subtype of `B`, then you should be able to use an `A` anywhere you can use a `B`.  This demonstrates that you can't use an `ArrayList<String>` everywhere you can use an `ArrayList<Object>`.

Answer (score 9):

This goes back to what it means for `A` to be a subtype of `B`. The formal name for this is the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which says basically that `A` is a subtype of `B` if and only if you can take any valid program that has in it something of type `B`, swap in something of type `A` and it would still be a valid program. The effect of this is that if you can use an `A` wherever you could use a `B`, then `A` is a subtype of `B`.

So in this case, since this is part of a valid (valid meaning "compiling") program:

```
public static void doThing(List<Object> x) {
  x.add(new Object());
}
```

Then, by the Liskov substitution principle, if `List<String>` were a subtype of `List<Object>` this would be part of a valid program too:

```
public static void doThing(List<String> y) {
  y.add(new Object());
}
```

But clearly that second snippet can't compile. Therefore, that second snippet is not part of a valid program, and therefore `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`.

Likewise, the other way around is also not true: `List<Object>` is not a subtype of `List<String>`. Finding the program snippet to prove that is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Great answer. I knew that part of the problem was a confusion I had with the word subtype, which implies a hierarchy. Put the word hierarchy in the middle of a discussion of Object and String in Java and you automatically think inheritance, which is obviously not what we are talking about here. Thanks.