# Cast exception from one class to another

Tags: java, hibernate, casting

```
 Session session2 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx2 = session2.beginTransaction();

      Query q=session2.createQuery("from studBean1 group by SNo");
        List<Student_change> l1=(List<Student_change>)q.list();
        //Student_change sc=new Student_change();



       for(Student_change sc3:l1){
           session2.save(sc3);
           tx2.commit();
           session2.close();
```

here the data coming from studBean1  i can access the data into Student_change

but it gives the excption can't cast from `studbean1` to `Student_change`

Comment: "here the data coming from studBean1 i can access the data into Student_change" - I don't understand this. Please edit your question to make it a *lot* clearer.

Comment: That would be because the object is not a Student_change object or one of its subclasses.

Comment: Well, yo are querying for `studBean1` objects and assigning them to `Student_change` objects. Their classes are different.

Comment: First `Student_change` is an ugly class name that doesn't confirm Java naming convention. You should do it precisely (may not be related to the concrete problem though).

Comment: is the studbean1 table mapped correctly to Student_change table in hibernate mapping?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have modelled `Student_change` as a generalisation of `studBean1`, a `List<studBean1>` is not a subtype of `List<Student_change>`. Try getting a `List<studBean1>`, iterating over it and perform the cast in the loop.

[why-is-liststring-not-a-subtype-of-listobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606428/why-is-liststring-not-a-subtype-of-listobject)

Anyway, there are more problems in your code which you should revise (see comments to your question).

Answer (score 0):

' query.list ' returns you a list of Type Object unless you use it with generics, 
in you current code you are returning a list of Object and trying to Cast it to List of Student

i believe casting the objects one by one should do

```
Session session2 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tx2 = session2.beginTransaction();

Query q=session2.createQuery("from studBean1 group by SNo");
List<Object> l1=Listq.list();
// Student_change sc=new Student_change();

for(Object obj:l1){
  Student_change sc3 = (Student_Change)obj;
  session2.save(sc3);
}

tx2.commit();
session2.close();
```

Comment: Right, but remember removing the cast to List of Student_change. Otherwise it will still not work.

Comment: @sorencito Thanks for pointing that out, i missed in CTRL+C -> CTRL+V :D