# Java - why does sending concrete implementation to a generic interaface as parameter does not compile?

Tags: java, generics

Why `doSomething2()` and `doSomething3()` don't compile in Java?

(`Toyota extends Car` and `Car implements ICar`)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Toyota> toyotas = new HashMap<>();
    doSomething0(toyotas);
    doSomething1(toyotas);
    doSomething2(toyotas);
    doSomething3(toyotas);
}

private static void doSomething0(Map<String, ? extends Car> cars) {}
private static void doSomething1(Map<String, ? extends ICar> cars) {}
private static void doSomething2(Map<String, ICar> cars) {}
private static void doSomething3(Map<String, Car> cars) {}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is List<String> not a subtype of List<Object>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606428/why-is-liststring-not-a-subtype-of-listobject)

Comment: `Map<String, Car>` is *not* a `Map<String, Toyota>`

Comment: @AlexShesterov "obviously", but the question is asking about the opposite situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Toyota> toyotas = new HashMap<>();
    doSomething4(toyotas);

    Toyota t = toyotas.get("hello"); // boom
}

private static void doSomething4(Map<String, Car> cars) {
    cars.put("Hello", new Honda());
}
```