# Why no type restriction in the following Java generic method?

Tags: java, generics

When define a generic method we can use T. In the following method it will allow us to pass two lists with the same types.

```
public static <T> void methodList(List<T> t1, List<T> t2) {    
}
```

So in main() we can pass two lists of String, but can not pass a list of String and a list of Integer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> stringList2 = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();

    methodList(stringList, stringList2); // correct
    methodList(stringList, integerList); // can't, reason: Incompatible equality constraint: Integer and String
}
```

My question in this. If we define a generic method like the following, it will allow us to pass different types.

```
public static <T> void method(T t1, T t2) {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "a";
    Integer num = 1;

    method(s, num); // correct
}
```

Why in this case there is no type restriction as in the first example?
Can we do it by ourselves, allow passing only the same types to the second method?

Comment: Both `String` and `Integer` are a subtype of `Object`, so `T` is inferred `Object`. The same can't happen with `List<String>` and `List<Integer>`, as neither are a subtype of `List<Object>`.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [Why is List<String> not a subtype of List<Object>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606428/why-is-liststring-not-a-subtype-of-listobject)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `method(s, num);` to be valid, there just needs to be a type `T` such that `Integer` and `String` are both convertible to `T`. `Object` is such a type. Java's type inference algorithm can infer such a type too (though IIRC it's some intersection type of interfaces that `Integer` and `String` both implement).

However, for `methodList(stringList, integerList)` to be valid, there needs to be a `T` such that both `List<String>` and `List<Integer>` can both be converted to `List<T>`. *There is no such type.* `Object` doesn't work here, because `List<String>` and `List<Integer>` cannot be converted to `List<Object>` ([See also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/5133585)). i.e. Java's generics are *invariant* by default.

If you make the type parameter of the `List`s covariant by saying `? extends T`, then `methodList(stringList, integerList)` compiles.

```
<T> void methodList(List<? extends T> list1, List<? extends T> list2) {}
```

Because `T` can be `Object` (or whatever intersection type Java actually infers), and both `List<String>` and `List<Integer>` can be converted to `List<? extends Object>`.

Comment: Thank you. Just one question for the first part. So T should be some superclass for both classes. I do not understand the conception, why is this? I mean why T is not an explicit class.