# A NavigableSet<String> does not match Collection<Object> in method argument

Tags: java, overloading

I have a method which takes a `Collection<Object>` where the `Object` can be a `String` or `CustomClass`. It then takes each element of the collection and passes it to a method with an argument of `Object` like so:

```
public void foo(Collection<Object> c) {
    for(Object o : c)
        bar(o);
}

public void bar(Object o) {
    if(o instanceof String || o instanceof CustomClass) {
        ...
    }
}
```

`bar` works fine when I pass it a `String` or `CustomClass`, but when I try to pass a `NavigableSet<String>` to `foo` I get `cannot find symbol; symbol : method foo(java.util.NavigableSet<java.lang.String>)`.

However if I change the the argument type in `foo` to `Collection<String>` it works fine, but this means I need to make a new `foo(Collection<CustomClass>)` method which will involve repeating code. Is there a way around this?

Comment: It's because [a `Collection<String>` is not a `Collection<Object>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Collection<String>` is not a subtype of `Collection<Object>`, therefore the compiler doesn't find any compatible methods. Put

```
public <T> void foo(Collection<T> c) {
  for (T o : c) bar(o);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The inheritance relationship between `T<A>` and `T<B>` is is called "generic covariance".
It is not as simple as, if `A` inherits from `B`, then `T<A>` inherits from `T<B>`, because the type parameter may be "in" or "out" (as C# would put it).

See for example http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html
or [java generics covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance)
or http://etymon.blogspot.co.uk/2007/02/java-generics-and-covariance-and.html

Marko's suggestion is the simplest fix for your problem.