# Java Generics passed in parameter errors

Tags: java, generics, parameters

I get a compilation error simillar to:
The method `visitParents(Class<C>)` in some type is not applicable for the arguments `(Class<MyClass>)`

MyClass is something like:      `public class SortableTable<T>{...}`

I prefer not to change the type parameter of SortableTable to `<C>` since many other classes will be effected negatively, also cannot change visitParents to take anything but `Class<C>` as a parameter.

Any potential solutions will be appreciated.

---

Thanks for your advice.
I will try to be as specific as I can without filling the page with code.

Error description on line "visitParents(SortableTable.class, visitor);":

The method visitParents(Class"<"C">", IVisitor"<"C,R">") in the type Component is not applicable for the arguments (Class"<"SortableTable">", IVisitor"<"Component,Void">")

```
public class SelectAllFilterPanel extends Panel{private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CorporateActionsPanel.class);

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public SelectAllFilterPanel(String id, final IModel<Boolean> model){
    super(id);

    add(new AjaxCheckBox("selectAll", model){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            // TODO - do this properly
            final AjaxRequestTarget requestTarget = target;

            IVisitor<Component, Void> visitor = new IVisitor<Component, Void>(){

                @Override
                public void component(Component component, IVisit visit) {
                    SortableTable<?> table = (SortableTable<?>)component;
                    table.visitChildren(CheckBox.class, new IVisitor<Component, Void>(){

                        @Override
                        public void component(Component component, IVisit visit) {
                            if (!component.getId().equals("selectAll")){
                                CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)component;
                                if (model.getObject())
                                    checkbox.setModelObject(true);
                                else 
                                    checkbox.setModelObject(false);
                                requestTarget.add(checkbox);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    visit.stop();
                }
            };
            visitParents(SortableTable.class, visitor);
            target.add(this);
        }
    });
}}
```

SortableTable Class:

```
public class SortableTable<T> extends DataTable<T, String> {    private HeadersToolbar headerToolbar;   

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public SortableTable(String tableId, SortableTableDataProvider<T> dataProvider, int maxRows) {
    this(tableId, dataProvider.getColumns(), dataProvider, maxRows);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public SortableTable(String tableId, List<IColumnConfig<T, String>> columns, ISortableDataProvider<T, String> dataProvider, int maxRows) {
    super(tableId, new java.util.LinkedList<IColumn<T, String>>(columns), dataProvider, maxRows);               

    addTopToolbar(new NavigationToolbar(this));                     
    addTopToolbar(headerToolbar = new HeadersToolbar(this, dataProvider));

    addBottomToolbar(new NoRecordsToolbar(this));

    setItemReuseStrategy(ReuseIfModelsEqualStrategy.getInstance());
}

public void setHeaderVisible(boolean visible) {
    headerToolbar.setVisibilityAllowed(visible);
}

public boolean isHeaderVisible() {
    return headerToolbar.isVisibilityAllowed();
}

@Override
protected Item<T> newRowItem(String id, int index, IModel<T> model)
{
    return new OddEvenItem<T>(id, index, model);
}}
```

visitParent signature is:

```
    public final <R, C extends MarkupContainer> R visitParents(final Class<C> parentClass,
    final IVisitor<C, R> visitor)
        {
            return visitParents(parentClass, visitor, new AllVisitFilter());
        }
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. Post the actual error not "something like". Tell us about the class heirachy, are you invoking with a subclass of `T`, a superclass of `T`?

Comment: Show us how you're calling the code.

Comment: *I prefer not to change the type parameter of MyClass to since many other classes will be effected negatively* we don't know for sure since you haven't shown the real problem.

Comment: Somewhere you still use a non-generic `Class klazz`, passed to someMethod? Use `Class<MyClass<T>> klazz`.

Comment: With generics, it helps to actually have the source code, as it is far too easy to be misled by common issues that seem to be the problem, when in fact it is a different issue that is causing the problem.  Try cutting out all of the non-relevant methods, the body of the methods you need to keep, and verify that the issue still exists before posting it.  That will have people looking at your exact issue without the confusion of non-important parts.

Comment: @DwB Ok, I have the balloon in my head.  Wait, you don't mean a birthday balloon, do you?  I was thinking of a manned balloon.  (just an example of how imagination isn't the fastest way to solve a problem)

Comment: Edwin Buck & @DwB I have given you the BALLOON and the user manual that came with it, hope that is enough information to help me fly. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood properly. But you can always use `Class<? extends Object>` which can accept any type of parameter

Comment: That would not be a possible solution for me. Sorry I was unclear on my initial question. I have included more details now. The issue is that my method's first parameter is supposed to be Class<C> but the class I pass to it is seen as Class<SortableTable>. I think I am missing something really obvious here but not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

You have `visitParents(Class<C>, Z.IVisitor<C,R>)`, with  `C=Component` and `R=Void` (because `visitor` is `IVisitor<Component, Void>`). 
But the type of `SortableTable.class` is `Class<SortableTable>`, which is not assignable to `Class<Component>` because **[generics are not covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance)**.

If you can change the signature of `visitParents`, do it:

```
 <R, C extends MarkupContainer>
  R visitParents(Class<? extends C> parentClass, IVisitor<C, R> visitor)
```

If you cannot change the signature of `visitParents`, then you need to convince the compiler that you actually have a `Class<Component>`:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 Class<Component> klass = (Class<Component>)(Class<?>)SortableTable.class;
 visitParents1(klass, visitor);
```

While the later approach is not technically safe, it works because on runtime the [**generic types are erased**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

When instantiating visitor I changed the first type (component) to SortableTable(which is a child of component) and hence the method visitParent compiles fine now. The issue was the second parameter in visitParents() not the first one.

```
                IVisitor<SortableTable, Void> visitor = new IVisitor<SortableTable, Void>(){

                @Override
                public void component(SortableTable component, IVisit visit) {
                    //SortableTable<?> table = (SortableTable<?>)component;
                    component.visitChildren(CheckBox.class, new IVisitor<Component, Void>(){

                        @Override
                        public void component(Component component, IVisit visit) {
                            if (component.getId().equals("selectAll")){
                                CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)component;
                                // TODO fix reference to client selection model
                                if (checkbox.getModelObject() && !clientSelectionModel.getObject())
                                    checkbox.setModelObject(false);
                                requestTarget.add(checkbox);
                                visit.stop();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    visit.stop();
                }
            };
            visitParents(SortableTable.class, visitor);
```

Thanks for the help guys.