# Java wildcards vs type parameters

Tags: java, generics

Why does 1 work and 2 not ?

1:

```
public List<? extends Integer> l1;
public List<? extends Number> l2 = l1;
```

2:

```
public List<U> l1;
public List<S> l2 = l1;
//where U and S have been previously defined as: **S extends Number,U extends Integer**
```

Comment: Can you show how you are defining them previously for your second example?

Comment: @SaurabhAgarwal isn't that the point?  Why does "any subclass" work but a _specific_ subclass doesn't ?

Comment: public class WildcardsTest<S extends Number,U extends Integer> {/* code presented above in 2 */}

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to with Integer being final, Eclipse comes up with the following warning when I implement your code: "The type parameter U should not be bounded by the final type Integer. Final types cannot be further extended"

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl: this doesn't work either
class A{}

class B extends A{}

public class WildcardsTest<S extends A,U extends B>{/* code presented above in 2 */}

Comment: To clarify, are `U` and `S` type parameters or classes?

Comment: @PaulBellora: U and S are type parameters in a generic class _declaration_.

Comment: @Razvan Okay, check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15790682/697449) and let me know if there's any further confusion.

Answer (score 3):

[Generics are not covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance). For example:

```
List<Integer> l1;
List<Number> l2;
l1 = l2; // incompatible types
l2 = l1; // also incompatible
```

However, wildcarded types offer a way to express covariance:

```
List<? extends Integer> l1;
List<? extends Number> l2 = l1; //legal
```

`l1` is being expressed as a `List` of *some unknown type* that is or extends `Integer`. Similarly, `l2` is a `List` of some type that is or extends `Number`. Since `Integer` extends `Number`, the compiler knows assigning `l1` to `l2` must be okay.

This situation is different:

```
<S extends Number, U extends Integer> void someMethod() {

    List<U> l1;
    List<S> l2 = l1; //incompatible types
}
```

`S` and `U` are type parameters, meaning they are provided some specific type arguments by callers of `someMethod` (or type inferrence). These type arguments could be a concrete type like `Integer` or a wildcard capture.

While they are also bounded, this is different from using bounded wildcards like above. Type parameters are bounded at declaration - within the method body they are understood not to change. For example, let's say both `S` and `U` were resolved to `Integer` by calling:

```
this.<Integer, Integer>someMethod();
```

In this case we can imagine the method body looks like this:

```
List<Integer> l1;
List<Integer> l2 = l1; // okay why not?
```

This would be legal, but we just happened to get lucky. There are many situations where it wouldn't be. For example:

```
this.<Double, Integer>someMethod();
```

Now we reimagine the method body:

```
List<Integer> l1;
List<Double> l2 = l1; // danger!
```

So you can see that a bounded type parameter is a something much different from a bounded wildcard, which allows different generic types to be covariantly "swapped in":

```
List<Integer> l1;
List<Double> l2;
List<? extends Number> l3;
l3 = l1;
l3 = l2;
```

Answer (score 1):

BTW: You cannot extend `Integer`, `Integer` is a `final` class.

```
// l1 holds any subclass of Integer and, because Integer implements Number it is also a subclass of Number
public List<? extends Integer> l1;
// l1 (see above) implements Number so this is fine.
public List<? extends Number> l2 = l1;

// Using Integer here instead of your U because you cannot extend Integer - it is final.
public List<Integer> l3;
// Make S extend Number
static class S extends Number {
  // Implementing the abstract methods of Number
}
// NOT valid because l4 must be a List of S not a list of ANY Number and l3 is a List<Integer> - no connection other than a commmon interface.
public List<S> l4 = l3;
```

Comment: Your language is a little confusing - I think you meant "subclass" in some places?

Answer (score -1):

Look In 1.1 you are saying any class which extends Integer and in 1.2 any class which extends Number. Now is such a way Integer is sub class of Number that's why it didn't give any error in 1st case. But is 2.1 you are saying only U and in 2.2 only S and you are doing

```
 public List<S> l2 = l1
```

and l1 is of type U not S and generics don't supports such object referencing by it's own. You will have to use wild cards like used in 1st case.

```
 public List<? extends Number> l2 = l1;
```

Will solve your problem..

Answer (score -2):

Because in 1 you are saying any sub class of the Integer and Number respectively.

But in second you are saying Generic of U and S and like this generics don't supports Super can refer Sub class object concept of java OOP's.

Comment: You may not accept it but it's the actual reason behind generics..!!