# Calling Generic-Defined Method in a Non-Generic-Defined Class in Main

Tags: java, generics

I have a class, GraphSearch, defined as such:

```
public class GraphSearch{
///code
}
```

In this class is the generics-parameterized method:

```
public static <T> int dsp(T start, Map<T, List<Pair<T, Integer>>> adjList, T goal) {
///code}
```

I have a main I do this setup and call the method as such:

```
GraphSearch g = new GraphSearch();
HashMap<String,ArrayList<Pair<String,Integer>>> k = new  HashMap<String, ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>>>();
////various setup to fill my map with valid stuff
///Pair is a class I made in my package
```

Then in main is

```
System.out.println("dsp from A to E is" + g.dsp("a", k, "e"));
```

I get an error.

```
The method dsp(T, Map<T,List<Pair<T,Integer>>>, T) in the type GraphSearch is not applicable for the arguments (String, HashMap<String,ArrayList<Pair<String,Integer>>>, String)
```

Well, why not? Is an ArrayList not a List? Is a String not a Generic-acceptable type? Is a Hashmap not a Map?

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is subtle, but it's based in the fact that [in Java generics, a `Type<A>` is not a `Type<B>`, even if `A` extends `B`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p).  Here, `A` is `ArrayList`, and `B` is `List`.

You defined a `HashMap<String,ArrayList<Pair<String,Integer>>>`, but your method expects a `Map<String,List<Pair<String,Integer>>>`.  Try defining `k` with `List` instead of `ArrayList`, and it should work:

```
HashMap<String,List<Pair<String,Integer>>> k =
    new HashMap<String, List<Pair<String, Integer>>>();
```

OR define your `dsp` method to work with `ArrayList` instead:

```
public static <T> int dsp(T start, Map<T, ArrayList<Pair<T, Integer>>> adjList, T goal) {
```

Additionally, even if it's allowed, you should access static methods such as `dsp` via an instance of the class.  It's preferred to access it with the class name, for clarity:

```
// GraphSearch.dsp instead of g.dsp.
System.out.println("dsp from A to E is" + GraphSearch.dsp("a", k, "e"));
```

Comment: Wow... that is rather bizarre, I think. It seems NOT intuitive to me that I can get away with "replacing" Map with Hashmap but not List with ArrayList in my definition of such an Object.

But maybe I'm looking at it in an uneducated viewpoint.

Comment: It is counter-intuitive. but think links rgettman and I provided show why it's the case.

Answer (score 3):

Because `Map<T, ArrayList<...>>` is *not* a subtype of `Map<T, List<...>>`. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance) (among others) for why.

Your generic should be `Map<T, ? extends List<Pair<T, Integer>>>` if you want to support that use case.

Another alternative would be to change `k` to be of type `Map<String,List<Pair<String,Integer>>>` -- this is preferable even if you do use the `? extends` syntax, as it lets you [program to the interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) and use polymorphism better. For instance, you won't have to change `k` if you later decide that the values should be `LinkedList`s instead of `ArrayList`s.