# Why can F<? extends Bar> not be assigned to F<Bar>

Tags: java, generics

Here is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
import java.util.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        bar( foo() );
    }

    public static List<? extends CharSequence> foo() {
        return null;
    }

    public static void bar(List<CharSequence> baz) {
        // Nothing to see here
    }
}
```

This results in

```
bar(java.util.List<java.lang.CharSequence>) in Test cannot be applied to (java.util.List<capture#672 of ? extends java.lang.CharSequence>)
```

1. Is there any possible way in which **this** example could fail? It is safe to cast `<? extends CharSequence>` to `<CharSequence>`, isn't it?
2. How should I work around this (in a more complex setup) if not via casting?

Comment: It's not safe to cast. I think, it's good to explain through an example. Imagine: `foo()` creates and returns a `List<String>`. Now, `bar()` tries to add a `CharSequence` to the list. Boom. If you want to make the `bar()` method more generic, you also have to define `List<? extends CharSequence>` as parameter (thus making it impossible to add anything except `null` to the list).

Comment: Because Generic types in Java aren't covariant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets use standard example. You have classes

```
class Fruit{}
class Apple extends Fruit{}
class Banana extends Fruit{}
```

Now lets say you have reference for all kinds of Fruit lists like

```
List<? extends Fruit> list;
```

This reference will let you hold not only `Fruit` list but also `Apple` or `Banana` lists.

```
List<? extends Fruit> list = new ArrayList<Apple>();
//lets say we add some apples here to list
```

Do you think it would be safe to let `List<Fruit>` handle list of `List<? extends Fruit>` like

```
List<Fruit> fruits = list;
```

Think about it. Via `List<Fruit>` ***you can add all kinds of Fruits*** to list. It means you would be able to add `Banana` to currently hold list of `Apples`.

That is why Java will not let you use result of `foo()` which is `List<? extends CharSequence>` as argument for `bar(List<CharSequence> baz)`.

Comment: `2) How should I work around this` it depends on what is your goal. You can change `bar` to accept `List<? extends CharSequence>` but that will not allow you to add anything to list via this reference.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when `foo()` returns the list, you don't know what the list has in it.

Let's say for example that `foo()` returns a list of `StringBuilder`. But now, `bar()` tries to add `String`s to it. You broke the type-safety of this list.

If the list doesn't change in `bar()` I suggest changing bar to accept `List<? extends CharSequence>` and then you're good.

Comment: In other words: It would be fine the other way around (e.g., http://ideone.com/KNYkpv), but not *this* way around. This way around requires a potential downcast.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Indeed.

Comment: So it is impossible to instantiate a class (`new Foo<Bar>( xyz() );`) if `xyz()` returns `<? extends Bar>`? Any way to get around this?

Comment: If the constructor of `Foo<T>` doesn't change the list than you're good. If you change the list, you might be needing to creating an inner copy of the list.