# method return value covariance for primitives. Is it works?

Tags: java, covariance

**since java 5;

I know that if in the base class I write:

```
public Number doSomething(){
...
}
```

in the child class I can write something like this

```
@Override
public Integer doSomething(){
    ...
}
```

But I have a question.

If in base class method returns 
 - primitive 
 - array
 - or Collection.

How can I use covariant at this case?

Comment: Can you give some example for those case? At least the base class methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no covariance between primitives. No primitive type is a sub type of any other. So you can't do this

```
class Parent {
    public int method() {
        return 0;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public short method() { // compilation error
        return 0;
    }
}
```

For the same reason, corresponding array types for `int` and `short` also are not covariant.

With array types, it's similar to your `Number` example

```
class Parent {
    public Number[] method() {
        return null;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public Integer[] method() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Similarly for `Collection` types

```
class Parent {
    public Collection<String> method() {
        return null;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public List<String> method() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note the generic type argument has to be compatible (no covariance in generics, [except in bounded wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1)).

Comment: Is not valid **Collection<Number>** in parent and **Collection<Integer>** in child?

Comment: @gstackoverflow No, because covariance doesn't apply to generic types. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance) and related questions/answers.

Comment: @erickson What was illegal? Anyway, cleaner like this. Thanks.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I think array of primitives is helpful example for this response

Comment: @gstackoverflow You mean you want me to add an example with primitives that doesn't work?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Sorry, I am about **int []** in parent and **short []** in child

Comment: @gstackoverflow That's the same as `int` vs `short`. Because `short` is not a sub type of `int`, neither are their corresponding array types. Added an edit.

Comment: @JimmyT. Do you mean in the sense of a `List<String>` overriding a return type of `List<?>`? If that is, that is an unchecked conversion, not covariance. Both are supported by `return-type-substitutability`.

Comment: I meant that `List<? extends Number>' can be replaced by `List<? extends Integer>`.

Comment: @JimmyT. Ah, yes. Thank you. I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

1. primitive : No
2. array : Only if its a subtype of the parent's array type
3. or Collection : Same thing as 2