# is the Java compile-time dispatch of parameters broken?

Tags: java, parameters, overloading, dispatch, method-dispatch

I already know that Java dispatches methods based on compile-time types. However I have a case, where I expect that to work, but it doesn't.

Consider this simple example:

```
class Foo{ 
    void bar(Object... objects) { //do something }

    void bar(Map<String, Object> map) { //do something else }
}
```

and the calling Code:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
HashMap<String, T> map = createSomeHashMap(); //wil generate HashMap
foo.bar(map);
```

WHY the heck Java is thinking it would be most appropriate to call `bar(Object... objects)`?
Since I have a Map at compileTime everything should work! Why I must explicitly downcast it like `foo.bar((Map<String, Object>)map);` ??

Comment: Java does not dispatch dynamically (at runtime) on parameters. The choice of method signature happens entirely during the compilation. And no, the selection is not "broken": it is well-defined by the JLS.

Comment: He did say "compile-time types". ;)  I think he has that bit right at least.

Comment: @markspace exactly! I don't even ask for "runtime dispatching"! I got the feeling that user28... don't even read my question, but just the subject (in which I admit I had a mistake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this program below and got an eror `Type mismatch: T cannot be converted to Object`:

```
public class DispatchTest
{

   private void bar( HashMap<String, Object> map )
   {
   }

   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      test();
   }

   private static <T> void test()
   {
      DispatchTest dt = new DispatchTest();
      HashMap<String,T> map = new HashMap<>();
      dt.bar( map );
   }
}
```

So I guess it's the generics that are messing you up.  Change the type of the parameter from `Object` to `?`, that worked for me.

```
private void bar( HashMap<String, ?> map )
{
}
```

Edit: Just to elaborate on this a bit, I put the code back to the original, and added a method like in your example `bar(Object...)`.  Here's the Java byte codes that are produced:

```
private static <T extends java/lang/Object> void test();
Code:
   0: new           #3                  // class quicktest/DispatchTest
   3: dup
   4: invokespecial #4                  // Method "<init>":()V
   7: astore_0
   8: new           #5                  // class java/util/HashMap
  11: dup
  12: invokespecial #6                  // Method java/util/HashMap."<init>":()V
  15: astore_1
  16: aload_0
  17: iconst_1
  18: anewarray     #7                  // class java/lang/Object
  21: dup
  22: iconst_0
  23: aload_1
  24: aastore
  25: invokevirtual #8                  // Method bar:([Ljava/lang/Object;)V

  28: return
```

You can see in this case the decision has already been made that the `Map` parameter is not appropriate and the invokevirtual byte code on line 25 wants the `Object...` version of the call.  That's done at compile time, not runtime.

If I change the code back to my suggestion (using `Map<String,?>`), then the invokevirual byte code asks for the Map parameter.  Your version works too because the cast forces the compiler to emit the invokevirtual for the Map, not the Object... it would normally resolve to.

Comment: I cannot change Methods from the `Foo` class, because it belongs to an API I use (ElasticSearch). I even don't wanted to have a working solution (had it solved through casting), but only was interested, WHY this is not working. I feel like it cannot be the Generic, because they are erased. You aren't even allowed to write two methods in the same class like this: `void bar(List<String> strings)` and `void bar(List<Integer> integers)` because for java its the same at runtime: `void bar(List<Object> list)`.

Comment: You arent't even allowed to compile you program (at least in eclipse). But mine did compile!

Comment: @Rafael T: Yes, generics are erased at runtime, however the decision on which method to call is made at compile time. Thus, generics figure into it and the first method bar(Object...) is called by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insides, but I'm really confused by now. But does it make sense, if ANY T is (at least) an Object? These Generics in Java are sucking so badly... They never work as expected!

Comment: Any `T` is not an Object.  Generics are [invariant, not covariant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance).  The type <Object> does not match the type <String> for example, because a type that holds Objects might have Numbers or JButtons, and Strings are a different type with generics involved.

Comment: so would it help to be a `Hashmap<String, T>` where T ins declared as `<T extends Object>`?

Comment: No, because T always extends Object.  T is `invariant` (See that link above.)  Basically it has to match exactly or it won't match.  Personally I think the API that you are calling is wrong.  They should use ? not Object.