# Cannot pass ArrayList<Impl> to method taking ArrayList<Interface>

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have an interface and a class implementing it:

```
public interface IFoo{
    Integer bar();
}

public class Foo implements IFoo{
    @Override
    public Integer bar(){
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Now in another class, I have a function which takes an ArrayList of the interface type.

```
public class Something {
    public static void function(ArrayList<IFoo> foos){
        //do something on foos
    }
}
```

I want to use this function on an array list of Foo:

```
ArrayList<Foo> myFoos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
Something.function(myFoos);//can NOT do this
```

What is the problem or what shall I do?

Comment: Slightly off topic, but why not `public static void function(IFoo foos...)` ?

Comment: I agree with @Leon. Coding to the *interface* is a good practice.

Comment: your interface name is IFoo and arraylist your are generating is for Foo. however inside Something class in function signature you have mentioned correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generics to the rescue!

```
public static void function(ArrayList<? extends IFoo> foos){
    //do something on foos
}
```

Now the function takes any kind of array list where the contained type is either `IFoo` or is derived from it.

For what it's worth, it's also a good idea to use the most generic type possible. Do you really need an `ArrayList`, or would any kind of `List` do? Or maybe any kind of `Collection`?

```
public static void function(List<? extends IFoo> foos);
public static void function(Collection<? extends IFoo> foos);
```

A good rule of thumb is to [be conservative in what you send and liberal in what you accept from others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle). Using more generic parameter types falls under the "be liberal" part.

Comment: Thanks. Collection type may depend.

Answer (score 1):

I would *probably* leave the method signature unchanged (except to accept an `List<IFoo>`) and promote the usage of the interface type, such as:

```
List<IFoo> myFoos = new ArrayList<IFoo>();
```

If *needing* to use `List<Foo>` - again, away with the ArrayList! - then I would likely still keep the simpler signature and force the caller to cast as appropriate, or otherwise provide a `List<IFoo>` expression, leaving the responsibility of such an operation at the call-site.

(I'm largely biased *against* subtyping, and prefer to sidestep this [covariance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance) entirely when practical.)

Comment: Okay, I'll bite. Why are you biased against subtyping?

Comment: @JohnKugelman Not so much subtyping as inheritance subtype-relationsips: mainly the increased (and too-easy) dependence upon LSP (beyond a defined interface contract) and concrete types.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I'm in agreement with you there. I thought you had something against wildcard qualifiers specifically. That'd be an oddly specific thing to hate. ;-)

Comment: @JohnKugelman Oh no, not at all - but if I can do away without such then I'll try and do so first. (This question isn't a really good example of when they really shine.)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using generics :

```
public static void function(ArrayList<? extends IFoo> foos){

}
```

So your problem is easily get solved.