# Java: casting a class having a type parameter

Tags: java, casting

I get a compile error "inconvertible types" for the following code at the line (B).  Conceptually, I believe it should work.  First, "adapter" is of type BasicAdapter, and BetaAdapter is a subclass of that.  Second, the type parameter BetaData is a subclass of AlphaData.

```
public class Test
{
  class AlphaData {} // base class for data

  class BetaData extends AlphaData {} // subclass for data

  class BasicAdapter<T> {} // a generic adapter

  class BetaAdapter extends BasicAdapter<BetaData> {} // adapter subclass with binding


  BasicAdapter<AlphaData> adapter = null; //(A)

  Test()
  {
    BetaAdapter ba = (BetaAdapter) adapter;  //(B)
  }
}
```

If I change the line marked (A) to

```
  BasicAdapter<BetaData> adapter = null;
```

it compiles.  That makes sense.  But I would like to figure out a way to make the original arrangement work.

Comment: You may want to check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant).  Also, the top answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance) looks relevant.

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p?lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BasicAdapter<? extends AlphaData> adapter = null;
```

would work (or compile at least). And it's compatible with

```
BasicAdapter<? extends AlphaData> adapter = new BetaAdapter();
```

Comment: This construct does, indeed, eliminate the compile error for this example.  I'm having some residual errors in my real code which I'm trying to simplify right now.

Comment: I realized that I've substantially changed the question.   So I'm marking your answer correct and submitting a new question for the residual problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you are specifying that

`class BetaAdapter extends BasicAdapter<BetaData> {}`

that means, BasicAdapter must be of type `BasicAdapter<BetaData>` if you try to typecast   `BasicAdapter<AlphaData>` to `BasicAdapter<BetaData>` then it will not work, because Type arguments must be compatible.

following code compiles  and makes sense as we are accepting all classes of AlphaData in the BetaAdapter class as type argument.

```
public class Test
{
  class AlphaData {} // base class for data

  class BetaData extends AlphaData {} // subclass for data

  class BasicAdapter<T> {} // a generic adapter

//changes made in following line...
  class BetaAdapter extends BasicAdapter<AlphaData> {} // adapter subclass with binding


  BasicAdapter<AlphaData> adapter = null; //(A)

  Test()
  {
    BetaAdapter ba = (BetaAdapter) adapter;  //(B)
  }
}
```

Comment: but (if you look at the code in the question) `class BetaData extends AlphaData` already

Comment: That would eliminate the compile error in my example. It isn't a good solution for me, though, because it would defeat type checking in the various methods in BetaAdapter.  Thanks for the idea anyway.