# Java generics and subtyping

Tags: java, generics

I'm really having trouble understanding at an intuitive level why the following causes a compile time error.

```
Collection<String> c1 = new ArrayList<>();
Collection<Object> c2 = c1;
```

I understand that the second statement above is illegal but I can't wrap my head around it. String is an Object but a Collection of strings is not a collection of objects ? What makes this illegal ? Everywhere I read the tutorials simply state that the inheritance relationship does not hold when dealing with generic collections but don't offer much explanation as to why.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant ?

Comment: If the next line of code is `c2.add(Integer.valueOf(5));`, what happens when someone relies on `c1` containing only Strings?

Comment: Because a `Collection<Object>` can do things that `Collection<String>` can't do, for example hold integers. Thus `Collection<String>` cannot be a subtype of `Collection<Object>`.

Comment: It's not about the actual objects in the list; obviously you can have a Collection<Object> that is full of Strings. It's about what type you can know the objects coming out of the list must be, the Collection<Object> enforces only that objects put in it are instances of Object.

Comment: Consider checking [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) in java; [(example here)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance).