# Java lambda: Expected Object but found MyClass

Tags: java, object, lambda, superclass

If I have:

```
public class MyClass{
    MyClass(Object b){
        //Some code here
    }
}
```

And I do:

```
MyClass X = new MyClass(new SomeOtherClass());
```

It works just fine, im assuming, because every class has Object as a superclass.

But, if I do:

```
import java.util.function.Predicate;
public class MyClass{
    MyClass(Predicate<Object> b){
        //Some more code here
    }
}
```

And then:

```
MyClass X = new MyClass((SomeOtherClass s) -> {
    //Even more code
    return true;
});
```

I get an error saying:

```
Incompatible parameter types in lambda expression: expected Object but found SomeOtherClass
```

Shouldn't I be able to send a `SomeOtherClass` object in that lambda expression?
I'm using the `Object` class because i wanna be able to recieve not only `SomeOtherClass`, but also `SomeOtherClassXPTO`.
I tried looking this up and found nothing so far, so my apologies in advance if this has been asked before.

Comment: A `Predicate<SomeOtherClass>` cannot be assigned to a `Predicate<Object>`, just as a `List<Integer>` can't be assigned to a `List<Object>`.

Comment: In that case, you need to have `Predicate<? extends Object>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, when you defined your predicate as `Predicate<Object>` it's restricted to only accept objects which `getClass()` method returns `Object`.

For this method to work you would be doing something like `Predicate<? extends Object>` but this does not make much sense. Use `Predicate<?>` alone then.

Otherwise, another way to solve this is to find the common denominator of your two classes, probably a parent class and use `Predicate<? extends ParentClass>`.

A final solution would be to create, depending on your application logic, an interface and implementing the interface by both objects to be able to something like the following `Predicate<? extends YourInterface>`

Comment: Seeing that `java.util.function.Predicate` is a "consumer" type, it doesn't make much sense to use `extends`-bounded wildcards in any case.

Comment: @newacct I dont know what you mean about this sentence. It makes total sense to me. Can you expand?

Comment: In Java there is a mnemonic: PECS -- "producer `extends`, consumer `super`". Basically, a class that only uses `T` by returning it is a "producer" of `T`, and should always be used with `? extends` bounds; whereas a class that only uses `T` by taking it as a parameter is a "consumer" of `T`, and should always be used with `? super` bounds. `Predicate` mainly takes `T` as a parameter in its `test` method, so is a consumer, and should be used with `? super` bounds.

Comment: If you think about it, a value of type `Predicate<? extends Something>` isn't useful, because you cannot pass anything but `null` to its `test` method.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance does not work for Generic parameter, the official doc about can be found [*here*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html)

---

You need to

```
MyClass(Predicate<? extends Object> b) {
    //Some more code here
}
```

or

```
MyClass(Predicate<?> b) {
    //Some more code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know, the following is valid:

```
Object o = new SomeOtherClass();
```

But, this doesn't apply to generics, because [generics are not covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance#answer-2660850):

```
Predicate<Object> p;

p = (SomeOtherClass s) -> false; // compiler error - incompatible parameter types...
```

The only possible assignment to the `Predicate<Object>` is:

```
Predicate<Object> p = object -> ... ;
```

At the same time, the input to this predicate can be of any type:

```
p.test(new Object());
p.test("");
p.test(99);
```

As stated in the Yassin's answer, consider `Predicate<? extends Type>` in order to gain flexibility.