# Assignment of a list of generics implementing an interface to a list of the same interface

Tags: java

***This question is about the relation of an interface to the class which implements the interface. I can not see how [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance) answers the question.***

I created an interface `Boxed` and an abstract generic class `Box`, which implements the interface. Then I create two concrete classes `IntegerBox` and `StringBox`. Then I created a list of elements, which extend `Box` with an `IntegerBox` value and a `StringBox` value. So far so good.

Now I want to assign `List<? extends Box>` to `List<Boxed>`. My expectation is, that this should be valid, because whatever extends `Box` implements also `Boxed`. But the compiler does not allow me. This is the error:

```
main.java:29: error: incompatible types: List<CAP#1> cannot be converted to List<Boxed>
    List<Boxed> lb2 = laeb; // does not compile, although every value which extends Box implements Boxed
                      ^
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Box from capture of ? extends Box
1 error
```

I can copy the list:

```
List<? extends Box> laeb = List.of (new IntegerBox(42), new StringBox("answer"));
List<Boxed> lb1 = new ArrayList<> (laeb);
```

Every element of the type `? extends Box` is used to create a value if the type `Boxed`. But the assignment reports an incompatible type. Why?

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class main
{
  static interface Boxed { }

  static abstract class Box<T> implements Boxed
  {
    T content;
    Box (T content) { this.content = content; }
  }

  static class IntegerBox extends Box<Integer> { IntegerBox (Integer content) { super (content); } }
  static class StringBox  extends Box<String>  { StringBox  (String content)  { super (content); } }

  public static void main (String ...arguments) throws Exception
  {
    IntegerBox i = new IntegerBox(42);
    StringBox  s = new StringBox("answer");

    List<? extends Box> laeb = List.of (i, s);

    Boxed b0 = i;  // => IntegerBox is compatible with Boxed
    Boxed b1 = s;  // => StringBox  is compatible with Boxed

    List<Boxed> lb1 = new ArrayList<> (laeb); // List<Boxed> can be created by values of "? extends Box"

    List<Boxed> lb2 = laeb; // does not compile, although every value which extends Box implements Boxed
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
List<StringBox> stringBoxList = new ArrayList<StringBox>();
List<? extends Box> boxList = stringBoxList; // works, StringBox extends Box

List<Boxed> boxedList = boxList; // suppose this *did* work
boxedList.add(new IntegerBox(42)); // this line definitely compiles, what does it do?
```

After the final line, `stringBoxList` would contain an `IntegerBox`, despite originally being an `ArrayList<StringBox>`.  That's bad.

That's what the compiler is preventing.

To get around this is as simple as

```
List<? extends Boxed> boxedList = boxList;

boxedList.add(new IntegerBox(42));
// forbidden by the compiler, because IntegerBox is not necessarily the _same_ subclass    
// of Boxed as boxedList's elements
```

Or, alternately, you could write

```
List<Boxed> boxedList = Collections.unmodifiableList(boxList);
```

...because the problem goes away if you can't modify the list.

(But, bluntly, [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/869736) covers this, just not the direct case of `? extends`.)

Comment: The conclusion `stringBoxList` contains a `IntegerBox` is wrong, because after the assignment `stringBoxList` is no `List<StringBox>` any more, it is now a `List<Boxed>`. and for `List<Boxed>` it is pretty fine to contain either `StringBox` or `IntegerBox`, because they loose their kind, when they become a `Boxed`.

Comment: @ceving: That's incorrect.  `stringBoxList` _is still_ a `List<StringBox>`.  A variable's type doesn't change when something else is assigned to it.  There's still only one `ArrayList` object, and it is, and always was, an `ArrayList<StringBox>`.

Answer (score 1):

> *Now I want to assign `List<? extends Box>` to `List<Boxed>`.*

You cannot do that, as `List<Boxed>` is not a supertype of your upper-bounded wildcard `<? extends Box>`.

Change:

```
List<Boxed> lb2 = laeb;
```

with:

```
List<? extends Boxed> lb2 = laeb;
```

---

> *`List<Boxed>` can be created by values of "`? extends Box`"*

With:

```
List<Boxed> lb1 = new ArrayList<>(laeb);
```

you are not really creating the list with `<? extends Box>` type, but you rather populate the new list, with already defined immutable list you create above - `List.of(i, s);`

---

Note, that:

- `extends` [has the semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) of both - `extends` and `implements` in Java Generics.

> Note that, in this context, extends is used in a general sense to mean either "extends" (as in classes) or "implements" (as in interfaces).

- Type Erasure works for interfaces alike. See [this quote from docs.oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html):

> The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.

Comment: But `Boxed` is the interface. And the interface gets never "extended" in my example.

Comment: Why is it necessary to talk about "? extends Boxed" if this actually never happens in the code? Or did it happen anywhere, I can not see? Is the interface also a victim of type erasure?

Comment: 1. `extends` has the semantics of `extends` and `implements` in Generics; 2. Type erasure works for interfaces as well. See the updated answer.