# What is the type of an Optional created from a constant different to one created from a stream?

Tags: java, types

Let's say I have an interface `Bar` and an implementing class `Foo`:

```
interface Bar { ... }

class Foo implements Bar {
  static final Foo X = new Foo();
  static final Foo Y = new Foo();
  static final Foo[] FOOS = { X, Y };
}
```

Now let's say I have a class with methods that return `Optional<Bar>`:

```
public class Fubar {

  public Optional<Bar> fromValue() {
    return Optional.of(Foo.X); // This is fine
  }

  public Optional<Bar> fromStreamA() {
    
    Optional<Foo> foo = Arrays.asList(Foo.FOOS).stream().findFirst();
    
    return foo; // This fails to compile
  }

  public Optional<Bar> fromStreamB() {

    Optional<Foo> foo = Arrays.asList(Foo.FOOS).stream().findFirst();
    if (foo.isPresent()) {
      return Optional.of(foo.get()); // This is also fine
    }
    return Optional.empty();
  }
}
```

The method `fromValue()` compiles correctly, however `fromStreamA()` does not. I get an error message along the lines of `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Optional<Foo> to Optional<Bar>`. I worked around this mismatch in `fromStreamB()` (which compiles correctly).

I'm having trouble understanding why `fromStreamA()` does not compile. I sense it's something to do with generics and is similar to why `List<Foo>` cannot be assigned to `List<Bar>`, however I can't grasp it. Can anyone explain why `fromValue()` is fine and `fromStreamA()` is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because [generics are not covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance): `Optional<Foo>` cannot be assigned to an `Optional<Bar>`.

The other example works because the compiler helps you infer the type to be `Bar`, i.e.:

```
Optional.of(Foo.X)
```

is equivalent to:

```
Optional.<Bar>of(Foo.X)
```

If you try to explicitly tell the inferred type to the compiler, it will not accept it:

```
Optional.<Foo>of(Foo.X);  // does not compile
```