# Swift, use generic property with different specific types - Reference to generic type requires arguments in

Tags: swift, generics, enums, protocols

How would one go about assigning an instance of a class which can have a generic type, but you don't know what type that is until run time?

For example.

We have a protocol and enums that conform to it like this:

```
protocol Stage: CaseIterable, Hashable {
    var fooBarLength: Int { get }
}
```

---

```
enum FirstStage: String, Stage {
    var fooBarLength: Int { 10 }
    case section1
    case section2
}
```

---

```
enum SecondStage: String, Stage {
    var fooBarLength: Int { 10 }
    case section1
    case section2
    case section3
}
```

---

Next we have some kind of controller that uses the protocol as a generic type... comme ça...

```
class FooBarController<StageType: Stage>: UIViewController {
    private var stages: [StageType: Float] = [:]
}
```

---

Then used like this:

```
func fooBarScreen(boop: SomethingThatKnowsAboutTheStages) {
    var fooBarController: FooBarController // <---- how do I define this????

    if boop.someCondition() {
        fooBarController = FooBarController<FirstStage>()
    } else {
        fooBarController = FooBarController<SecondStage>()
    }
}
```

In Java / Kotlin I could just do this as it is above, how do I achieve the same thing in Swift?

Currently I get

```
"Reference to generic type 'FooBarController' requires arguments in <...>"
```

**Secondary Question**

Is there a more generic way than having to use that if-statement here? Ideally I would like the `fooBarScreen` method to not care about the generic type and just have `SomethingThatKnowsAboutTheStages` provide the type for me.

Comment: Where is `fooBarScreen` method declared?

Comment: Are you sure you can do this in Java? Making this would work would require covariant generics, which AFAIK Java doesn’t support ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance)). If this were possible, hypothetically, the issue is this: `fooBarController` can be one of two different types, depending on a runtime condition (`boop.someCondition`). Generally that leads to issues like this: `let x = fooBarController.stages`, what’s the static type of x? In this case that isn’t an issue because `stages`, but you see the point

Comment: @Alexander yep absolutely works in Java...   https://gist.github.com/kaylanx/877d8d77094ff3e7820f5ef1139966f1

Comment: @LeoDabus just in another class

Comment: @kaylanx Huh, what the heck, you can just omit the generic type parameters in Java? I've never seen this before... what would that even mean? Does it act as if you had `FooBarController<java.lang.Object>`? 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a protocol for providing `Stage` types like so:

```swift
protocol StageProvider {
    
    associatedtype T: Stage
    
    func getType() -> T.Type
    
}
```

Then make your `SomethingThatKnowsAboutTheStages` or any other one conform this protocol:

```swift
class SomethingThatKnowsAboutTheStages: StageProvider {
    
    typealias T = SecondStage
    
    func getType() -> T.Type {
        SecondStage.self
    }
    
}
```

Add an initializer for your `FooBarController`:

```swift
class FooBarController<StageType: Stage>: UIViewController {
    
    convenience init(stage: StageType.Type) {
        self.init()
    }
    
}
```

And finally use all these:

```swift
func fooBarScreen<T: StageProvider>(boop: T) {
    let controller = FooBarController(stage: boop.getType())
}
```